# Adding infix operator to expression parser

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to add a parser for infix operators to a simple expressions parser. I have already looked at the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec3-1.0.0.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Expr.html) and at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987104/parsing-non-binary-operators-with-parsec), but it seems like I am missing something.

```
import qualified Text.Parsec.Expr as Expr
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as Tokens
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.Parsec

data Expr = Number Integer
          | Op Expr Expr
          | Boolean Bool
      
instance Show Expr where
  show (Op l r) = "(+ " ++ (show l) ++ " " ++ (show r) ++ ")"
  show (Number r) = show r
  show (Boolean b) = show b

parens = Tokens.parens haskell
reserved = Tokens.reservedOp haskell

infix_ operator func =
  Expr.Infix (spaces >> reserved operator >> spaces >> return func) Expr.AssocLeft

infixOp =
  Expr.buildExpressionParser table parser
  where
    table = [[infix_ "+" Op]]

number :: Parser Expr
number = 
  do num <- many1 digit
     return $ Number $ read num

bool :: Parser Expr
bool = (string "true" >> return (Boolean True)) <|> (string "false" >> return (Boolean False))

parser = parens infixOp <|> number <|> bool

run = Text.Parsec.runParser parser () ""
```

This parser is able to parse expressions like `1`, `false`, `(1 + 2)`, `(1 + false)`, but not `1 + 2` (it's parsed as `1`). If I try to change the parser to `parens infixOp <|> infixOp <|> number <|> bool`, it get stuck.

What should i change in order to parse expressions like `1 + 2` without parenthesis?

Comment: What does "get stuck" mean in this context?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Recursion without a base case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the `infixOp` parser at the top level like this:

`run = Text.Parsec.runParser infixOp () ""`

Otherwise the your infix expressions can only be parsed when occuring in parentheses.

The attempt to use `parens infixOp <|> infixOp <|> number <|> bool` most likely gets stuck because it loops: `parser` tries to parse using `infixOp`, which tries to parse using `parse` and so on...

These tutorial might help you getting started with parsec (they did for me):

https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsing_a_simple_imperative_language

http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/002_parsers.html